# How to convert a List to IEnumerable?

Tags: c#, list, ienumerable

I was solving a problem which needs to write a function that returns only the integers from an object List(I have written the function but it doesn't work). I have thought for a long time how to convert the List to IEnumerable, I was searching how to solve the problem, but I haven't found the right solution yet. Please, can anyone help me with this, maybe easy, problem?

```
public static IEnumerable<int> GetIntegersFromList(List<object> listOfItems)
{
    List<object> result = new List<object>();
    for (int i = 0; i < listOfItems.Count - 1; i++)
    {
        if (listOfItems[i] is string)//the input is only integers and strings
        {
            listOfItems.RemoveAt(i);
        }
    }
    return listOfItems;//this doesn't work
}
```

Comment: What about it doesn't work?

Comment: `return listOfItems.OfType<int>();`?

Comment: The issue is not List vs IEnumerable but int vs object. You're trying to return IEnumerable<object> (as a List) but expects IEnumerable<int>.

Comment: Read the [yield](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/yield) documentation.

Comment: `listOfItems.RemoveAt(i);` Lets say there are 10 items in the list. You are up to the 5th item. You remove it. Which item do you think will be looked at next?

Comment: Why do you declare `result` only to never use it?

Comment: `return listOfItems.OfType<int>()` has the advantage of not modifying the pass-in object, which is quite unexpected from a method named "Get…".

Answer (score 10):

You don't convert a list to `IEnumeruble<T>` - a list is already an `IEnumerable<T>`. The problem in your code is that the list of `object`s is *not* an `IEnumerable<int>`.

You have three approaches to solving this:

- Make a new `List<int>`, populate it in your loop, and return it, or
- Use `yield return` to avoid constructing the list explicitly, or
- Apply LINQ's `OfType<int>` to `listOfItems` to get the result in a single line of code.

Answer (score 4):

As the other answer says, Linq is one way to go.

Here is a compact one liner method with out testing it.

```
public static IEnumerable<int> GetIntegersFromList(List<object> listOfItems)
{
    return listOfItems.Where(i => i is int)).Select(i => (int) i).ToList();
}
```

It can even be shorter

```
return listOfItems.OfType<int>().ToList();
```

Thx to @Blake Thingstad and @mjwills for their input.

Comment: I would recommend just doing `.Where(i => i is int)`. OP had not a string, but that's a backward way of getting the ints and would fail if there were ever any objects in the list that are not an int or string.

Answer (score 1):

```
static void Main()
{
   List<object> dd = new List<object>() { 1, 2, "a", "b", 8 };

   var dd2 = new List<int>(GetIntegersFromList(dd));

   dd2.ForEach(j => Console.Write("{0}\t", j));

    Console.ReadKey();
}

public static IEnumerable<int> GetIntegersFromList(List<object> listOfItems)
{
      return listOfItems.OfType<int>().ToList();
}
```